# Bootstrap issues with responsive spacing

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have been working on this snippet of code for 3 days now trying to figure out what I am doing wrong and I have just given up. Currently I am trying to add a spacer between my images except for the center icon only when the browser or phone is set to a sm or below. I have tried an @media to check for width, I have also tried bootstrap mt-md-2 but still it does nothing.. Here is my code, I hope I can find out what I am missing.

```
  <body>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-3 margin-3">
      <div class="atomix">
      <img src="img\atomix.png" alt="Atomix" class="img-responsive mx-auto d-block"/>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-3">
        <div class="Rectangle playersOnline mx-auto d-block">
          <p><span data-playercounter-ip="atomixprison.net">0</span> online</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-3">
<div class="navBar1">
  <img src="img/NavBar1.png" class="img-responsive mx-auto d-block" alt="navbar"/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row margin-4">
  <div class="col-lg-5 col-xs-3 mt-md-2">
    <div class="webStore mt-md-2">
      <a href="https://atomixnetwork.buycraft.net/"><img src="img/webstore.png" alt="webstore" class="mx-auto d-block img-responsive"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-xs-3 margin-15">
    <div class="forums">
      <a href="https://www.atomixprisonmc.net/"><img src="img/forums.png" alt="forums" class="mx-auto d-block img-responsive"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-5 col-xs-3 mt-md-3">
    <div class="discord mt-md-3">
      <a href="https://discord.gg/D63c9JM"><img src="img/discord.png" alt="discord" class="mx-auto d-block img-responsive"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js\bootstrap.min.js">

</script>
```

Comment: try bootstrap offset i.e col-md-offset-2

Comment: What version of Bootstrap are you using? There is no `-xs` in Bootstrap 4. Create a working Codeply or Fiddle that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 1):

To handle the spacing between grid elements, you have the **offset**.

The whole documentation is here : [Bootstrap Grid Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) (section "Offsetting columns")

Just like Shireesha answered you, you will probably need something on your divs like :

```
.col-md-offset-*
```

where the * is the amount of space you need.

Answer (score 0):

try this out this may help you

```
<div class="col-12 mb-3 mb-sm-0"></div>
```